# mask a portion of image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
Image1=imread('depthmp.png');
[row1,column1]=size(Image1);
B = imresize(Image1, [375 150]);
[row3,column3]=size(B);
subplot(2, 2, 1);
imshow(Image1);
mask = zeros(row3, column3, 'uint8');
mask(30:300, 5:150) = 255;
subplot(2, 2, 2);
imshow(mask);
subplot(2,2,3);
C=imadd(mask,Image1);
imshow(C);
```

Here is my code to mask a portion of image.but am getting an error.The error is as follows
"Error using imadd (line 69)
X and Y must have the same size
and class or Y must be a scalar
double."
Can anyone sort out the problem please????

Comment: The line `mask(200:300,200:300)=255;` is not clear. you enlarge `mask` to be with 300 columns. The error says that `mask` and `Image1` is not in the same size- you used `resize`, and after that change again the size of `mask`... maybe what you mean is not to write the line that i mentioned, and write `C=imadd(mask,B);`

Comment: i have deleted that line..my aim is to get a portion of a image.remaining part of the image must be black.

Comment: Try `C=mask.*B;` Note that `mask` has the dimensions of `B`, not of `Image1`. Also, note that to have portion of the original image you need to multiply the mask, not add it.

Comment: Thanks for the information.I tried to check the size of the mask and Image1.Both are same.Now the error is like"Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree. " Where might i have gone wrong??

Comment: what are the dimensions of `B`, `mask`, `Image1`? Is `C=mask.*Image1` works?

Comment: dimension of  image 1 =376*1350 B=375*450 mask=375*450;i tried to multiply B and mask.

Comment: Which format are they? maybe try `C=double(mask).*double(B);`? I have no more ideas...

Comment: "Image1" and "mask" are not of the same size! On the contrary, images "mask" and "B" are the same size. Are you sure you do not what to combine "B" and "mask"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so basically you want the masked part of array keep unchanged and not masked make black - right?
so it can be done easily with replacing values outside mask with 0 value (I'm doing something like this in my PhD work)
I'm copying the masked part into black square

do something like this

```
Image1=imread('lena.jpg');
[image_rows,image_columns]=size(Image1);

mask_rows = 100;
mask_columns = 100;
mask_rows_position = 10;
mask_column_position = 10;  
C = zeros(image_rows,image_columns,'uint8'); %prepare black image
masked_image = Image1(mask_rows_position:mask_rows_position+mask_rows-1,mask_column_position:mask_column_position+mask_columns-1);
C(mask_rows_position:mask_rows_position+mask_rows-1,mask_column_position:mask_column_position+mask_columns-1) = masked_image;
imshow(C);
```

if you need explanation of what's that don't hesitate to aks
good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable comments..it worked.i tried another method like extracting each channel and doing the masking.but it is lengthy..this code is really good :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, if I understand your question correctly, you need this:

```
Image1=imread('lena1.tif');
[row1,column1]=size(Image1);
B = double(imresize(Image1, [375 150]));
[row3,column3]=size(B);
subplot(2, 2, 1);
imshow(Image1);
mask = zeros(row3, column3);
mask(30:300, 5:150) = 1;
subplot(2, 2, 2);
imshow(uint8(mask));
subplot(2,2,3);
C=B.*mask;
imshow(uint8(C));
```

It is a matter of doing calculations using double numbers and converting them to uint8 only when needed to display the images.

Answer (score -3):

Image1=imread('O.jpg'); Image1=rgb2gray(Image1); [row1,column1]=size(Image1); B = imresize(Image1, [375 450]); [row3,column3]=size(B); subplot(2, 2, 1); imshow(Image1); mask = zeros(row3, column3, 'uint8'); mask(30:300, 5:150) = 255; mask=imresize(mask,[375 450]); subplot(2, 2, 2); imshow(mask); subplot(2,2,3); C=imadd(mask,B); imshow(C);

Comment: Format your code and always describe what your doing or explain your answer